# Xbox360 to Dell All-in-one through HDMI cable, no sound

Tags: xbox-360

When I connect my XBox 360 to my Dell All-in-One desktop through HDMI hook-up and switch to the HDMI source on my monitor, I get picture with no sound. How can I get sound?

Answer (score 2):

- First, you need to check if your monitor supports sound over HDMI(Not all support it believe me)
- Second, check if your Xbox audio settings are in the stereo mode
- Third, check your volume.

Answer (score 0):

The key-phrase is this:

> Dell All-in-One desktop

This monitor is not even a monitor.  It is a PC attached to a monitor.

The speakers may not be part of the monitor.  It may be PC speakers that happen to be mounted to the side of the monitor, but hooked up to the PC.

You'll have to look at the specification of your device and see whether it really supports audio via HDMI.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1.Make sure the sound isn't muted and the volume is turned up on your TV.

2.Make sure the [console audio settings](https://support.xbox.com/en-IN/xbox-360/console/configure-audio-settings) are correct for your combination of TV and cables.

3.[Update](https://support.xbox.com/en-IN/xbox-360/console/system-updates-info) your console software.